# What does Peter Dinklage eat on camera in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, production, acting

I recently discovered that Peter Dinklage is a vegan, which means that he neither eats meat nor does he eat any products produced by animals, like milk and honey.

So what does he eat in scenes where you see him biting off a bone?

Comment: Lena Headey (who plays Cersei) is also a long-time vegetarian. Maybe it runs in the family? ;-)

Comment: The answer below shows that he is actually vegetarian, not vegan. Do you have some source that contradicts that?

Comment: The word "vegan" is used in his german entry on Wikipedia

Comment: Vegetarian since 16, vegan since 2014 according to: http://www.contactmusic.net/game-of-thrones/news/peter-dinklage-fronts-new-vegan-film-for-peta_4158416 (which is the source quoted in the German wikipedia).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Peter Dinklage** is a vegetarian. He has been a meatless eater since the age of 16.

> In all of the scenes that require him to be eating meat with his dear family in King’s Landing, Dinklage eats **tofu or fake meats** instead.
>
> <sub>[Source 1](http://www.peacefuldumpling.com/good-news-bad-news-vegan-game-thrones-fans) (emphasis mine)</sub>

He quotes:

> "I wouldn't hurt a cat or a dog – or a chicken or a cow. And I wouldn't ask someone else to hurt them for me. That's why I'm a vegetarian."
>
> <sub>[Source 2](http://www.goliath.com/tv/10-things-you-didnt-know-about-actor-peter-dinklage/)</sub>

Comment: So he could still drink milk/eat honey or consume other animal products that don't involve harming animals.

Comment: @JAB exactly, that's the difference between Vegetarian and Vegan.

Comment: @TaylorAllred I pointed that out because, as Thunderforge noted, the question says he is a vegan but the answer says vegetarian.

Comment: As I commented above, he is now vegan: http://www.contactmusic.net/game-of-thrones/news/peter-dinklage-fronts-new-vegan-film-for-peta_4158416